# Estrutura de projetos Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-pattern, padrão-dao

Estou com dúvidas no local onde trabalho, existem muitos projetos com muitas classes diferentes, e eles utilizam padrões que não aprendi na faculdade.

Padrões como: DTO, Canonico, Entity.

Dentro desses "formatos" de classes, existem outras classes que são builders e converters(Dto pra Canonico, Canonico pra Entity, Canonico pra Dto)

Alguém consegue explicar mais afundo oq são esses padrões e como funciona cada classe(DTO, Canonica, Entity).

Ps: A entity eu já sei como funciona, só coloquei pra falar tudo oq usamos aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Os padrões de projetos também são conhecidos conhecidos como Design Patterns, então quando ouvir esse termo, pode ter certeza que estará se referindo ao mesmo tema.
O objetivo dos padrões de projeto ou design patterns, são tornar componentes reutilizáveis que facilitam a padronização, que permita agilidade para as soluções de problemas recorrentes no desenvolvimento do sistema. Existem diversos tipos de padrões de projetos atualmente, te explicar o que é cada um deles aqui seria muito complicado, pois é um tema bem longo e abrangente. Sugiro que de uma lida nesse documento.
https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-os-conceitos-dos-padroes-de-projetos-em-java/29083

DTO - Data Transfer Object é um padrão de projetos bastante usado em Java para o transporte de dados entre diferentes componentes de um sistema, diferentes instâncias ou processos de um sistema distribuído ou diferentes sistemas via serialização.
A ideia consiste basicamente em agrupar um conjunto de atributos numa classe simples de forma a otimizar a comunicação.
 Ex : se voce tem uma classe com 50 atributos, e em uma determinado trabalho, tu precisa carregar carregar apenas 3 deles. 
O que fazer ? Pensando em melhorar o desempenho do processo, é criado um DTO (que nada mais é do que uma classe comum), onde irá receber os dados dessa classe passando apenas os 3 atributos que voce quer utilizar. 
https://www.devmedia.com.br/diferenca-entre-os-patterns-po-pojo-bo-dto-e-vo/28162

Converter = Nada mais é do que uma classe que irá receber um valor aleatório e irá converter os dados desse objecto de forma natural. Geralmente utilizados em projetos JSF…
Quando se trabalha com SelectOneMenu (ou SelectManyMenu) e entidades em JSF ocorre quando queremos que o value do nosso SelectItem seja a própria entidade, e não o “id” da mesma. Quando se popula um tipo de objeto geralmente você tem uma referencia dele no “campo” seja um id, email, etc. Geralmente voce quer trabalhar com ele por completo e nao com pedaços dele. Então a classe converter faz a conversão desse valor da tela para um objeto do tipo da entidade.
http://www.rponte.com.br/2008/07/26/entity-converters-pra-da-e-vender/

Sobre Modelo Canonico conheço muito pouco, mas toma um artigo legal que achei aqui na net.
https://sensedia.com/blog/soa/o-que-e-modelo-canonico/

Bons Estudos